When working with Routes and Controllers in PHP the route is not found and is returning a 404 error message
I am trying to create an MVC app but get an error message when creating the Route and Controller section
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';

// Extract the path component from the full URL of the current request

$request = trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), "/");
$request = trim($request, "/");

$routes = [
    "GET" => [
        "" => ["controller" => "\app\controllers\PostController", "method" => "index"],
        "posts/show/([0-9]+)" => ["controller" => "\app\controllers\PostController", "method" => "show"],
        "admin/posts/create" => ["controller" => "app\controllers\AdminController", "method" => "create"]
    ],
];

$path = $request;

$method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

foreach ($routes[$method] as $route => $info) {
    $pattern = preg_replace("#/([0-9]+)#", "/([0-9]+)", $route);
    if(preg_match("#^$pattern$#", $path, $matches)){
        echo $matches[1];

        $controller = new $info["controller"];
        echo $controller;
        $id = $matches[1];
        if($method == "POST" && $info["method"] != "delete"){
            $controller->{$info["method"]}($_POST, $id);
        } else{
            $controller->{$info["method"]}($id);
        }
        break;
    }
}

if(!isset($controller)){
    http_response_code(404);
    require  BASE_DIR . '/app/views/404.php';
    exit;
}

It is supposed to return the PostController method "show" or "index" but doesn't.
I am not able to find any error in this code.

Is the server (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc.) configured to pass through to PHP correctly? Also, can you confirm if this is your server's 404, or you app's 404?

I am working with PHPStorm / Jetbrains IDE, where it's all built in.

I also have an .htaccess file RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

To the second part of my comment, can you confirm where the 404 is coming from? Also, since we can't see your controllers, can you confirm that they call exit?

Have you checked the error log?  It seems to me that echo $matches[1]; will at least generate a warning if the pattern does not contain a parenthesised expression.  I suggest you debug $request and $pattern within your loop to see if it's all as expected

Also I note that in some of your controllers you're using a full namespace (starts with backslash), but for the last one you're using a relative namespace (without backslash).  That's not a problem if this file is in the root namespace already, but it might reduce the risk of errors later if you are consistent.

Although this is more of a personal preference, and not related to your problem, if you use PostController::class your IDE will be better able to understand and refactor things for you, too.

@ChrisHaas "call exit"? they use the GET -> on two urls, one is "" the original url and then there is "/posts/show/id" which leads to show method being triggered.

@RobEyre yes I am following a tutorial, and this code is provided by them. I don't know if it should be full path or relative path.

@RobEyre I added echo $matches[1] to see if it consists of any matches at all because there are no error messages produced. I did the same thing with $route=posts/show/([0-9]+) and admin/posts/create $pattern = posts/show/([0-9]+) and admin/posts/create as well

I apologize, with essentially no code comments, dynamic classes (new $info["controller"];) and methods ($controller->{$info["method"]}($_POST, $id)) that we can't see the source for, string interpolation in RegEx ("#^$pattern$#"), and relying on conditional variable creation none of which are wrong, we're left to manually mentally parse this. In this case I missed that $controller was created in the loop, and then outside of the loop a check is made for the non-existence of it.

My comment about calling exit was related to a pattern where function/method routes call exit or die when they are done. If the functions don't, then usually the controller does. Because I had missed the guard for the variable that is conditionally created in the loop, the absence of the exit would have meant that if if a controller was found, the 404 would have still kicked in. But I was mistaken in that, so we can ignore it. That all said, can you confirm where the 404 is coming from, the server or your application?

In PostController and AdminController, are you specifying a namespace?  If not, then I think you may have misunderstood the difference between namespaces and filesystem paths

To debug, I suggest adding var_dump($pattern, $path); just before the if(preg_match(...)) line.  Then you can examine what is being tested.
